# How to iterate over binary string in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, bind-variables

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OPji.png)

```
declare

str varchar2(2000) := :inputstr;
v_len number;
currChar CHAR(1);

begin
                v_len := length(str);
                for i in 1..v_len
                Loop
                        currChar  := substr(str,i,1);
                        if currChar = 1 then
              dbms_output.put_line('curr index' || i);
                        end if;
                End loop;
end;
```

When I pass '000111000' as input to IN_STRING variable , it trims the string and behaves very unusually.Please suggest some good approaches to iterate over binary strings like this.I am expecting output as 4,5,6 from above operation.

EDIT1:
Please don't directly input the string as str varchar2(2000) := '000111000';
Instead input it from bind variable as I mentioned above.

Comment: What is the unusual behaviour, and what are you expecting to see? And how are declaring, setting and passing the bind variable? (The code you posted is missing `declare` and `end;` but it would also be useful to include your `var in_string ...` line and how you set that value. With that as a varchar2 it seems to work OK.)

Comment: Please see image attached.updated question also

Comment: That seems to be a quirk of the dialog box; it appears to be inferring the bind variable data type based on the value, and is treating this as a number, so losing the leading zeros. (I can see the same thing in version 21.4.) I don't think you can make it do what you want with that dialog box. You'll have to use `var` and run it as a script I think, as shown in MTO's answer - setting the `in_string` bind value between the `var` declaration and the anonymous block..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works so long as you pass in a `VARCHAR2` data type (and not a `NUMBER`).

You can also tidy up the code passing in the bind variable only once and using `CONSTANT`s to hold the values that are constant:

```sql
VARIABLE in_string VARCHAR2;

DECLARE
  c_string CONSTANT VARCHAR2(200) := :in_string;
  c_length CONSTANT PLS_INTEGER := LENGTH(c_string);
  v_out    CHAR(1);
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1..c_length
  LOOP
    v_out := SUBSTR(c_string,i,1) ;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_out);
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> 0
> 0
> 1
> 1
> 1
> 0
> 0
> 0
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=933734b01f19a534bd7675190304de60)*

Comment: With bind variable ,it does not seem to work for me.Attached screenshot in question.Please see

Comment: @netcoredev Try explicitly declaring that the bind variable is a `VARCHAR2` data type using a `VARIABLE` declaration. You can also try upgrading to the latest version of SQL Developer.

Comment: This approach worked for me with few modifications.Thanks @MT0

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't behave unusual, unless datatype of `in_string` variable is `NUMBER` (then leading zeros don't have any meaning) - switch to `VARCHAR2`.

Illustration:

1. NUMBER variable datatype
2. value you enter
3. result - really, missing leading zeros

[image]

---

Otherwise, it works OK (this is SQL*Plus so I used substitution variable):

```
SQL> DECLARE
  2     v_length  NUMBER (10);
  3     v_out     VARCHAR2 (20);
  4  BEGIN
  5     v_length := LENGTH ( '&&in_string');
  6
  7     FOR i IN 1 .. v_length
  8     LOOP
  9        v_out := SUBSTR ( '&&in_string', i, 1);
 10        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (v_out);
 11     END LOOP;
 12  END;
 13  /
Enter value for in_string: 00111000
0
0
1
1
1
0
0
0

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Another option (if you're interested in it) doesn't require PL/SQL:

```
SQL>     SELECT SUBSTR ( '&&in_string', LEVEL, 1) val
  2        FROM DUAL
  3  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH ( '&&in_string');

V
-
0
0
1
1
1
0
0
0

8 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: can we do the same with only bind variables ?

Comment: Sure; you'd just substitute `'&&in_string'` with `:in_string`.